# haskell identifier recognition

Tags: parsing, haskell, regular-language

my working in file parsing using Haskell, and I'm using both `Data.Attoparsec.Char8` and `Data.ByteString.Char8`. I want to parse an expression which can contains symbols like : **- / [ ] _ .** (minus, slashes, braquets and underscore).

I've write the following parser

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import qualified Data.Attoparsec.Char8 as A

identifier' :: Parser B.ByteString
identifier' = A.takeWhile $ A.inClass "A-Za-z0-9_//- /[/]"
```

... but it's not works like expected.

```
ghc>  A.parse identifier' (B.pack "EMBXSHM-PortClo")
Done "-PortClo" "EMBXSHM"

ghc> A.parse identifier' (B.pack "AU_D[1].PCMPTask")
Done ".PCMPTask" "AU_D[1]"
```

can someone help me.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/attoparsec/0.10.1.0/doc/html/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString-Char8.html#g:9

To add a "-" to a set, place it a the beginning or end of a string.

The latter doesn't parse because you don't have dots in your class listing.

Comment: @FOPALéonConstantin you don't have the point in your argument to A.inClass -- just add it!

Comment: @FOPALéonConstantin, you are looking in the wrong position. Answers looks like `Done rest_of_string result`

Answer (score 1):

You want to allow `'-'` characters in identifiers, but `A.inClass` uses `'-'` for ranges. You have to put it at the start or end of the range string:

> To add a literal `'-'` to a set, place it at the beginning or end of the string.
>
> — [attoparsec documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/attoparsec/latest/doc/html/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString.html#v%3ainClass)